# php compressing images showing varying results

Tags: php

I was using the firebug page speed utility and one of the suggestions given was to compress the images - So I wrote the following code to compress the image

```
$filename="http://localhost.com/snapshots/picture.png";
$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
imagepng($img,null,9);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Now the actual image size is 154K
So I experimented by giving different quality levels and here is what I found

```
imagepng($img,null,0); --> Size = 225K
imagepng($img,null,1); --> Size = 85.9K
imagepng($img,null,2); --> Size = 83.7K
imagepng($img,null,3); --> Size = 80.9K
imagepng($img,null,4); --> Size = 74.6K
imagepng($img,null,5); --> Size = 73.8K
imagepng($img,null,6); --> Size = 73K
imagepng($img,null,7); --> Size = 72.4K
imagepng($img,null,8); --> Size = 71K
imagepng($img,null,9); --> Size = 70.6K
```

Do these results look accurate - I'm not sure why with quality 0 - the image size is larger than the actual size.

Secondly is this the best way to go about in PHP to compress images before rendering them in the browser to improve performance.

Based on the suggestions, that its better to compress the image once at the time of saving - I digged up the code that is called by the flash program to generate the snap shot -

```
$video = $this->_getParam('video'); 
$imgContent = base64_decode($this->_getParam('snapshot'));
file_put_contents("snapshots/" . $video . ".png", $imgContent);
```

**EDITED**
Based on Alvaro's suggestion, I have made the following modification to the code which generates a much small jpg file

```
$video = $this->_getParam('video'); 
$imgContent = base64_decode($this->_getParam('snapshot'));
file_put_contents("snapshots/" . $video . ".png", $imgContent);

$filename="snapshots/".$video.".png";
$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
imagejpeg($img,'test.jpg',75);
```

So now this is a 3 step process

1. create the initial image using file_put_contents
2. Use imagecreatefrompng and imagejpeg to compress the file and generate a smaller image
3. Delete the orig image

Is this the best optimal way to go about it.

Comment: what's the bit depth of the original image?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what bit depth means - Thanks

Comment: Do you require a PHP solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PNG uses lossless data compression, the only way to achieve a decent compression in a PNG image (edge cases apart) is to save it as palette (rather than true colour) and reduce the number of colours. You appear to be processing some sort of screenshots. You may obtain smaller file sizes is you use a lossy compression, i.e., save as JPEG. In either cases, you reduce both file size and picture quality. You could also try the GIF format, which tends to be smaller for small graphs.

Last but not least, you should compress images once (typically when they get uploaded), not every time they're served. I suppose your code is just a quick test but I mention just in case.

**Answer to updated question:**

I'm not familiar with PHP image functions but you should probably use a combination of [imagecreatefrompng()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) and [imagejpeg()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). Also, consider whether you need to keep the original PNG for future reference or you can discard it.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for the good pointers - It did'nt occur to me to save them originally in jpg or gif format - right now there is a flash webcam recorder that records the video and creates a snapshot image into a directory from where I'm reading to display in the browser - I might have to do a proper fix and see how the image is being saved initially rather than compressing it everytime as @Chochenos also suggested the same approach - Thanks

Comment: Please look at my edited question where i've posted the code that is saving the png file

Comment: Thanks Alvaro - I was able to use the functions you mentioned to create a jpg file which brought down the size way down. But right now I have a 2 step process - Step 1) using file_put_content - generate the image. Step 2) Using imagecreatefrompng and imagejpeg compress the image. Also there is no requirement for me to hold onto the original png file. So I will need a 3rd step to delete that file. So this three step process - is it the best way to go about it - thanks

Comment: I have updated the question to include your suggested way of generating the jpg file - Thanks

Comment: If you read the tip at the imagecreatefrompng() manual page, you'll see you can use fopen wrappers and there appears to be one to read from memory (`php://memory`). However, using temporary files is a very common approach and there's nothing wrong with it. See if http://es.php.net/tmpfile can make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

You have not understood the last parameter, that's not quality that's the compression level so increasing it will decrease the image size. Anyway i've used that method before to compress png images and it works well so i think you should continue to use it.

Comment: thanks mck - yes I was aware that the last parameter was the compression level but on the php manual they refer to it as quality which is why I used that term. Thanks for confirming that I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

1- The result seems accurate since `0` means **no compression**

> quality
>
> Compression level: from 0 (no
>   compression) to 9.

It's normal for the `0`ed file to be larger than the original (that can be slightly compressed to begin with). You need to understand file compression and PHP GD image constructor.

2- IMHO, the wisest choice would be to compress your png file before uploading them on your server (of course, it states only if you have the choice : static, few files).

Help for that :

- http://www.webreference.com/dev/graphics/compress.html
- http://www.punypng.com/
- http://omaralzabir.com/reduce_website_download_time_by_heavily_compressing_png_and_jpeg/

If it means to be dynamic, the php is the choice.

Comment: Thanks Chouchenos - I had read somewhere that irrespective of what compression level u specify the size cannot be more than the original image - but I guess I need to understand the whole file compression stuff before commenting on that.

Comment: Thanks for the links - right now I dont have the option of compressing them before uploading so I have to go with this option - but thanks for the resources. Appreciate it.

Comment: Please look at my edited question where i've posted the code that is saving the png file